# How do I write the conditions when a user clicks a specific button in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this user-interface in Microsoft Excel that appears when a user clicks a button (at a previous stage) this is then the user interface that appears.
[image: User Interface]

I'm having trouble writing the condition if a user clicks a button. For example when a user clicks a button, I want to create a relevant table, then fill the table with the relevant data.

I have the last 2 macros down, all I need is the code for the condition when a user clicks a specific button.

Here is what I have now (This is the code for when the user selects the 2018-2019 button)

```
 Option Explicit
        
 Sub Run_All_QB_Macros()

  'shows the userform when user clicks button on main menu

  show_qb_uf

  ' If User clicks 2018-2019 season button then **(THIS IS THE PART I'M HAVING TROUBLE WRITING**)


  ' Create the table for the 2018-2019 season

    qb2018_Create_Table



' Fill out the 2018-2019 season Table with relevant data

  querydatafromMySQL_2018qbs


   End Sub
```

Comment: Right clicking the button shows a menu with an "Assign Macro" option. This allows you to allocate a macro to run when the button is pressed.

Comment: In the VBA editor, each button has a `click` handler.  In each button's click handler, call the macro.

Comment: @VirtualMichael You're not understanding correctly: I have a button with an assigned macro already in the main menu & when I click it, brings up the interface above, right-clicking a button here does nothing

Comment: @Marc where can I access this click handler for a button?

Answer (score 1):

You are handling all the code in one `Sub`. It doesn't work like this.

Your userform launch code goes in a separate procedure (Perhaps in a `Module` or `Sheet code Area`) and the click events of the userform goes in `Userform code area`

Here is an example

You launch the Userform from a module

```
Option Explicit

Sub Run_All_QB_Macros()
    'shows the userform when user clicks button on main menu
    show_qb_uf
End Sub
```

[image]

Now let's say the `Userform` has three Command Buttons called `CommandButton1`, `CommandButton2` and `CommandButton3` as shown below.

[image]

In the userform code area (you can access it by double clicking on the `Command Button`), you need to handle each button click separately. Something like this

```
Option Explicit

'~~> If User clicks 2018-2019 season button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    '~~> Create the table for the 2018-2019 season
    qb2018_Create_Table
    
    '~~> Fill out the 2018-2019 season Table with relevant data
    querydatafromMySQL_2018qbs
End Sub

'~~> If User clicks 2019-2020 season button
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    '~~> Create the table for the 2019-202 season
    qb2019_Create_Table
    
    '~~> Fill out the 2019-2020 season Table with relevant data
    querydatafromMySQL_2019qbs
End Sub

'~~> If User clicks 2020-2021 season button
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    '~~> Create the table for the 2020-2021 season
    qb2020_Create_Table
    
    '~~> Fill out the 2020-2021 season Table with relevant data
    querydatafromMySQL_2020qbs
End Sub
```

[image]

**Note**: In `CommandButton2` and `CommandButton3`, I have taken sample names based on what you have for `2018-2019`. Change as applicable.

Comment: I got all of it working now except the function "qb2018_Create_Table" , I get a Compile error saying :"Expected variable or procedure, not module. How can I fix it?

Comment: You will have to share the code for `qb2018_Create_Table`